# Using self-hosted GitLab as Oauth Provider

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I managed to succefully install django-allauth and configure my app to allow authentication via Google Oauth2, but when i try to configure GitLab Oauth2 integration it juste fail with the message:

`The redirect URI included is not valid.`

I did set 
`http://xxx.xxx.xx/accounts/gitlab/login/callback/` as Callback url

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to whitelist the redirect URLs of your app in GitLab.

Admin Area -> Applications -> Your Django App -> Callback URL